# Dockercontainer with Nginx share the same network but can´t reach each other

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

recently I'm trying to set up a litte Home Server with a buildin DNS.
The DNS Service is given by lancacheDNS and set up in combination with a Monolithic-Cache (Port 1234) in two docker containers on 192.168.178.11 (Host machine) in my local network.
Since I want to serve a Website(Port 8080) along with some independent APIs (Ports 8081, 8082 or whatsoever) I decided to use Nginx as a reverse Proxy.
The DNS does the following:
getr.me --> 192.168.178.11
The routing works completely fine and getr.me:8080 gives me my website as expected.

Now the tricky part (for me);
Set up Nginx such that:

website.getr.me --> serving website

api1.getr.me --> serving the API1

api2.getr.me --> serving the API2

For that I created a Newtwork "default_dash_nginx".
I edited the nginx to connect to that via:

`networks:  default: name: default_dash_nginx external: true`

Also I connected my website serving container (dashboard) to the network via `--network default_dash_nginx`.
The serving website gets the IP 172.20.0.4 (received via `docker inspect default_dash_nginx`) and also the nginx server is connected to the network.
Nginx works and I can edit the admin page.
But unfortunaly event though I edited the proxyHost to the IP + Port of my website receiced from the network, the site is not available. Here the output of my network inspection: https://pastebin.com/jsuPZpqQ

I hope you have another Idea,

thanks in advance,

Maxi

Edit:
The nginx container is actually a NginxReverseProxyManager Container (I don´t know of it was unclear above or simply not important)

The Nginx container can actually Ping the website container ang also get the HTML files from Port 80 from it.
So it seems like the nginx itself isn´t working like it should.

The first answer got no results( I tried to save it as every of the mentioned files
[here](https://nginxproxymanager.com/advanced-config/#custom-nginx-configurations)

Do I have missed something or am I just not smart enough?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

nginx config, try and understand

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api1.getr.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api2.getr.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some.getr.me;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:XXXX;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to iclude these lines ( I do understand them) but the NPM (NginxProxyManager) actually doesn´t seem to like this kind of manipulation. It wants me to use the GUI configuration.